# Create reference type List(Of Objects) from source list

Tags: .net, system.reflection, typedescriptor, propertydescriptor, system.type

I have used following code to create new instance of specific destination Type using source object where i copied all primitive type property values from source object to destination object:

```
Function GetDestinationObjectFromSourceObject(pSourceObject As Object, pDestinationType As Type) As Object
            Dim oDestinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance(pDestinationType)

            For Each oPropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(pSourceObject)
                If TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(oDestinationObject).Contains(oPropertyDescriptor) Then
                    TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(oDestinationObject).Item(oPropertyDescriptor.Name).SetValue(oDestinationObject, oPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(pSourceObject))
                End If
            Next

            Return oDestinationObject
End Function
```

Now. i have a List(Of Class1) and want to get List(Of Class2) using same generic approach.
Here i want to pass List(Of Class1) and destination type (i.e. GetType(Class2))
How can i achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then you can iterate over List(of Class1) and pass each object to this method and add the object which is getting returned to a fresh List(of Class2).

for example (I am putting a code in c# as i am a little weak in vb.net but converting it into vb.net should not be a problem for you)

If this is not what you require then please rephrase your question.

```
List<Class2> newlstClass2 = new List<Class2>();
foreach(Class1 item in lstClass1)
{
    newlstClass2.Add(GetDestinationObjectFromSourceObject(item, typeof(Class2)));
}
```

EDIT:

The following is a generic method for your requirement. I am assuming that the classes are having a parameterless constructor. I have tested it a little from my end. Please do a thorough testing at your end as well.

```
public List<U> GenerateList<T, U>(List<T> lst)
{
    List<U> newLst = new List<U>();

    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        U obj = Activator.CreateInstance<U>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo item2 in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (obj.GetType().GetProperty(item2.Name) != null)
            {
                obj.GetType().GetProperty(item2.Name).SetValue(obj, item2.GetValue(item, null), null);
            }
        }

        newLst.Add(obj);
    }

    return newLst;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This can be solution but its not generic for all types of list as here you code "List<Class2> newlstClass2 = new List<Class2>();" which also i want to make generic should be done based on destination Type not " new List<Class2>();".